# Is there a way to break out of @tailrec in Scala?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I have a method that is recursive. Is there a way in scala to break out based on the size of the buffer (as shown below)? A case for breaking out when elementList.size > 5 for example?

```
val elementList = ListBuffer.empty[Book]
@tailrec
def getBooks(elements: List[Element]) {
  elements match {
    case Nil => info("Reached end of elements list.")
    case element :: rest if element.getElementType == ElementType.BOOK => {
      elementList.append(element.getBook) 
      getLooks(rest)
    }
    case _ => getBooks(elements.tail)
  }
}
```

Comment: consider using standard functions like elements.filter(_.getElementType==ElementType.BOOK).take(5)

Comment: You can use the nuclear option and write ``return``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the most simple way would be to just wrap an `if` statement around your `match` statement like this:

```
val elementList = ListBuffer.empty[Book]
@tailrec
def getBooks(elements: List[Element]) {
  if (elementList.size <= 5){
    elements match {
      case Nil => info("Reached end of elements list.")
      case element :: rest if element.getElementType == ElementType.BOOK => {
        elementList.append(element.getBook) 
        getLooks(rest)
      }
      case _ => getBooks(elements.tail)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could alternatively add an extra `case xs if elementList.size > 5 => ()`

Answer (score 0):

Genereally speaking you could try to pass down the number of remaining elements in the recursion.

For example:

```
  def get(list: List[Int], max: Int): List[Int] = {

    @tailrec
    def get(list: List[Int], acc: List[Int], remaining: Int): List[Int] = {
      list match {

        case h :: tail if remaining > 0 =>
          get(tail, h :: acc, remaining - 1)

        case _ =>
          acc
      }
    }

    // Requires reverse() !
    get(list, Nil, max).reverse
```

As for the accumulator: you could use a buffer instead, to prevent the `reverse()` at the end.